# Micropython: bytearray in json-file

Tags: json, micropython

i'm using micropython in the newest version. I also us an DS18b20 temperature sensor. An adress of theses sensor e.g. is "b'(b\xe5V\xb5\x01<:'". These is the string representation of an an bytearray. If i use this to save the adress in a json file, i run in some problems:

- If i store directly "b'(b\xe5V\xb5\x01<:'" after reading the json-file there are no single backslahes, and i get b'(bxe5Vxb5x01<:' inside python
- If i escape the backslashes like "b'(b\xe5V\xb5\x01<:'" i get double backslashes in python: b'(b\xe5V\xb5\x01<:'

How do i get an single backslash?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't save `bytes` in `JSON` with `micropython`. As far as `JSON` is concerned that's just some string. Even if you got it to give you what you think you want (ie. single backslashes) it still wouldn't be `bytes`. So, you are faced with making some form of conversion, no-matter-what.

One idea is that you could convert it to an `int`, and then convert it back when you open it. Below is a simple example. Of course you don't have to have a `class` and `staticmethods` to do this. It just seemed like a good way to wrap it all into one, and not even need an instance of it hanging around. You can dump the entire `class` in some other file, `import` it in the necessary file, and just call it's methods as you need them.

```py
import math, ujson, utime


class JSON(object):
    @staticmethod
    def convert(data:dict, convert_keys=None) -> dict:
        if isinstance(convert_keys, (tuple, list)):
            for key in convert_keys:
                if isinstance(data[key], (bytes, bytearray)):
                    data[key] = int.from_bytes(data[key], 'big')
                elif isinstance(data[key], int):
                    data[key] = data[key].to_bytes(1 if not data[key]else int(math.log(data[key], 256)) + 1, 'big')
        return data
    
    @staticmethod
    def save(filename:str, data:dict, convert_keys=None) -> None:
        #dump doesn't seem to like working directly with open
        with open(filename, 'w') as doc:
            ujson.dump(JSON.convert(data, convert_keys), doc) 

    @staticmethod
    def open(filename:str, convert_keys=None) -> dict:
        return JSON.convert(ujson.load(open(filename, 'r')), convert_keys)
    

#example with both styles of bytes for the sake of being thorough
json_data = dict(address=bytearray(b'\xFF\xEE\xDD\xCC'), data=b'\x00\x01\02\x03', date=utime.mktime(utime.localtime()))

keys = ['address', 'data'] #list of keys to convert to int/bytes

JSON.save('test.json', json_data, keys)

json_data = JSON.open('test.json', keys)

print(json_data) #{'date': 1621035727, 'data': b'\x00\x01\x02\x03', 'address': b'\xff\xee\xdd\xcc'}
```

You may also want to note that with this method you never actually touch any `JSON`. You put in a `dict`, you get out a `dict`. All the `JSON` is managed "behind the scenes". Regardless of all of this, I would say using `struct` would be a better option. You said `JSON` though so, my answer is about `JSON`.